# Visual Studio- disable specific waring doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have encountered a problem with vs++ settings. I get couple of C4834 warnings which come from boost and when I try to disable them via

> Project Settings->C/C++->Advanced->Disable specific warnings

nothing happens and I get the same warning all the time. 
In my command lline there is

> /W3 /wd"4834"

which accordingly to msvc specification should do the work. I've read some similiar topic about it but again none of them works for me.

Comment: According to the documentation, the usage of such option should look like: "_For example, `/wd4326` disables compiler warning C4326._" Note the lack of quotes

Comment: The problem is that the visual studio adds the quotes itself and when I try to do it by adding it to additional options it simply doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `#pragma warning( disable :4834)` as alternative.